# Is 8 / 9 better than 7 / 9 in terms of straight?

Tags: straight

Is 8 / 9 better than 7 / 9 pre-flop in terms of straight? I know that 8 / 9 is better than 5 / 9 for example because chances are you can get a "top straight". But I'm not sure if 8 / 9 is better than 7 / 9 or is J / Q better than 10 / Q? Or is it equal?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can think about the potential of connectors and gappers in terms of the possible straight draws that you can flop:

87:  JT, J9, T9, T6, 96, 95, 65, 64, 54

86:  T9, T7, 97, 95, 75, 74, 54

85:  97, 96, 76, 64, 54

84:  76, 75, 65

As you can see, the more connected your holding, the more frequently the flop contains a straight draw.  The more gapped your holding, the less frequently the flop contains a straight draw.  Moreover, the more gapped your holding, the less likely your straight draw is to the nuts.

For reference, check out [this video on Suited Connectors vs Suited Gappers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpdeOrlFOaU) by Guerilla Poker on YouTube.

Comment: Wow, thank you! Makes total sense. So connectors ARE better. Not sure if I should comment here or "answer my question". Let me know. Thanks.